# Extracting tesla revenue data through web scraping in python

Tags: web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, data-science

There is no revenue data being shown in the output, i am new to web-scraping and i might be missing out some key concepts required. i am aware it is some kinda silly mistake

[image]